# Как правильно объединять PHP и HTML?

Tags: php, html

Работают оба способа, но какой лучше использовать?

PHP в HTML:

```
текст текст текст <?= $text ?> текст
```

Заворачивание HTML в переменную, `print`, `echo` и т.д.:

```
echo "текст текст'.$text.' текст";
```

Comment: Не правильно объединять php и html! Лучше использовать шаблонизаторы

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk а шаблонизаторы по вашему кэшируют(рендерят) данные иначе?

Comment: @Tatatrin вот пусть они этим и занимаются. Думаю, речь была об этом. Мешанина из PHP-кода (отвечающего за логику) и из HTML-кода (отвечающего за отображение) в одном файле, по моему мнению, выглядит кошмарно. И это не зависит от размеров проекта.

Comment: @Regent в вопросе был пример `<?= $text ?>` то есть не про логику. а про вывод динамической информации.  А это вполне легальный и нормальный способ.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это да. Можно меня обвинить в додумывании за автора и/или в пессимизме, но я счел, что автор планирует весь код в таком стиле писать.

Comment: @Regent $text это вызов функций, логика в классах.
Ну вообще да, динамичная информация.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно же `php` в `html`, как минимум так делают толковые шаблонизаторы, в сторону которых я вам советую посмотреть.

Не исключено, что нужно будет вставлять `html` в `php`, но это минимум кода.

Answer (score 1):

Если ставить вопрос именно так, то первый вариант шаг в более верном направлении. При этом логику (php код) из таких файлов стараться по максимуму выносить, готовя данные заранее, чтобы осталось только распечатать все как надо (т.е. использовать php как шаблонизатор). Ну и в целом почитать про шаблонизаторы и MVC, чтобы не городить лапшу, даже если это пока и не использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Все способы правильные. Какой использовать – исходите из интересов тех, кто работает с кодом: вас и других разработчиков.

В длинном html в одном месте вставить одну переменную удобнее через `<?php echo $variable; ?>`.

Собрать из нескольких переменных, в цикле, какую-то небольшую html конструкцию, наверное, удобнее через `echo` или мной любимый `printf()`, где удобно не смешивать переменные и html:

```
printf('<li class="%s" %s>Item %d</li>', $myClass, $active, $n);
```

В более крупном проекте, где, возможно, один человек занимается php, а совсем другой – html вёрсткой, пора переходить на шаблоны.

Answer (score 0):

По Вашему вопросу, можно использовать и тот и другой случай.Автор отходите от устаревших методов разработки, почитайте и изучите паттерн проектирования Model View Controller, при этом Вам пригодятся знания ООП. В дальнейшем, Вы будете разделять все по полочкам, Controller для обработки форм и контроля данных, Model для работы с СУБД, View для представления контента, т.е отображение html наполнителя.

Comment: Предположу что возникло недопонимание.
Под $text я имел ввиду информацию, полученную из функции. 
Возможно неправ, но я уже изучил mvc, и вроде как следую его концепту:
Весь функционал содержится в функциях, которые в свою очередь находятся в классах.
Вызов функций происходит в шаблонах, которые и генерируют страницу для пользователя. Выбор шаблона происходит по параметрами из урл.